# JS/JQuery on keypress proper usage

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on creating a more accessible navigation, and in particular want to use determine whether a keypress is used. While I want to figure out why this is not working for me, I also want to know the difference between several methods that do the same thing. Those methods are:

`$('ul li a').on('keypress', function(e){...});`

& `$('ul li a').keypress(function(e) {...});`

& `$('ul li a').bind('keypress', function(e) {...});`

What is the difference if any? And is there a 'right' one to use for this siutation? Either way, none of them are actually working for me. I have setup console logs throughout the script I have written and while the console is logging the script loading, it detects the keydown, however it does not detect the return key being pressed, the whole script looks like:

```
$('ul li a').on('keypress', function(e){
   if(e.keyCode==13){ // return / enter key
       console.log("Return Key Pressed");
   }
   return false;
});
```

Thanks!

** EDIT **

I never discovered why the return key (or down arrow) was not working, neither would trigger the keydown event in the console, but I did discover the spacebar is the best method for accessibility, the end result looked like:

```
   $('ul li a').on('keypress', function(e){
        if ((e.keyCode || e.which) == 32) { // spacebar
            ... script ... 
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Internally, `.bind` maps directly to `.on` in the current version of jQuery. (The same goes for `.live`.) So there is a tiny but practically insignificant performance hit if you use `.bind` instead.

  However, `.bind` may be removed from future versions at any time. There is no reason to keep using `.bind` and every reason to prefer `.on` instead.

If you look in the source code for `$.fn.bind` you will find that it's just an rewrite function for `on`:

```
function (types, data, fn) {
    return this.on(types, null, data, fn);
}
```

- For `keypress` function,  i don't recommend it because it work only for exsiting elements ; if element will be exist after running `keypress` , it will not handle new elements.

  Instead you can use `delegate` :

  ```
  $(document).delegate('ul li a','keypress',function(event){
        //........
  })
  ```

Comment: `delegate` is way old syntax, why recommend this as opposed to `on`?

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, that certainly helped clarify everything for me. Would using `keypress` for elements you know will always exist be preferred? Also, any idea why the keypress is not being recognized using any of the methods?

Answer (score 0):

`.on()` is the preferred way to do all events in jQuery 1.7+

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method provides all functionality required
>   for attaching event handlers.

From the official docs: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Other methods of attaching events appear to be deprecated:

> For help in converting from older jQuery event methods, see .bind(), 
>   .delegate(), and .live().